# Why is there no tasks folder in active record gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

when I read through active record source on github repo, I can find active_record/tasks folder there but in the gem I install through `gem install`, that folder is missing. why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's new in Rails 4 and so only on master branch, if you have a look at the tag for the version you installed (e.g. [here for 3.2.9](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v3.2.9/activerecord/lib/active_record)), you'll see that the folder is not there either.

Comment: thanks, andy, what i am wondering is in current rails version like 3.2.9, what gem include those tasks which I want to use in a non-rails project

Comment: They are in ActiveRecord, just in [a different location](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.9/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the entire repo to go into the gem (the .git folder for example) There's a files var in the gemspec where you set what goes in.